# Помогите настроить zsh. WSL2. Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wsl, zsh

Запускаю терминал открывается zsh, пытаюсь открыть bash
выводит

```
zawert@huawei  ~  bash
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
...
```

Пытаюсь повторно, все успешно

```
zawert@huawei  ~  bash
zawert@huawei:~$
```

такая же проблема если открываю многие другие приложения

```
 zawert@huawei  ~  n
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)

...

22 updates can be applied immediately.
To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable


Last login: Mon Dec 27 13:07:01 MSK 2021 on pts/1
 zawert@huawei  ~ 
```

Куда посмотреть? Какая причина такого повидения? Помогите

Comment: В домашней директории есть `.hushlogin` и `.motd_shown`? Если нет, создайте, оставив их содержание пустым, перезапустите Ubuntu.

Comment: После перезапуска пусто

Comment: Проблема решена?

Comment: Нет. Проблема не пропала.

Comment: Тогда сформулируйте суть вопроса так, чтобы было ясно в чём же суть проблемы, без "потока сознания".